# Twitter Fabric TWTTweet image shrinks

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, twitter-fabric

I am using fabric for showing the `tweetView` everything is fine but sometimes some tweets has images with a wrong size

```
 self.tableView.register(TWTRTweetTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "tweetCell")

 TwitterOAuth.getTimelineTweets(String(self.count), completion: { (data) in
                if let trendArr = data as? NSArray {
                    self.homeTweets = TWTRTweet.tweets(withJSONArray: trendArr as [AnyObject]) 
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
           })
```

[image]

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. This was a bug in version 2.4.0, version 2.5.0 has the fix. From the release notes [here](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/changelog.html#id38):

"Fixed bug where Retweets with photos did not layout correctly".

If you update to the latest version, the issue should be resolved.

Comment: thanks @Mike, also when you tap a tweet cell, the detailView has a black background sometimes, hope that fixed too as well. thanks for the feedback again